# ArcPy Calculate Null Values to Zero in Multiple Fields

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, python-toolbox

I have a table that has Null values and I would like to insert a portion in my script to calculate these Null values to 0 in only a few of my columns in my table.

Here is my script so far:

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target, "ELEM_STUD") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0] = None
            cursor.updateRow(row)

    del row
```

Target is my table, which is a parameter that is defined prior to this portion of my code.

The error that I am getting is in the first line, stating that 'ELEM_STUD' is not defined. That is the first of multiple fields I would like this script to run through.

I have also tried to add `removeNull ("ELEM_STUD")` after my cursor and haven't had any luck there either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can work on more than one fiel at the time, and use some list comprehension to go through your row

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target, ("ELEM_STUD","second_field","thirdfield") ) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            newrow = [0 if x == None else x for x in row]
            cursor.updateRow(newrow)
```

Comment: This did the trick, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the `target` does refer to a proper feature class.

You need to check whether your field value is None first. If yes, then update with 0.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(target, "ELEM_STUD") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None:
            row[0] = 0
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Alex, that works great, thank you very much. I have 9 more fields, what would be the best way to update those fields? Copying the cursor seems inefficient to me but the only way I can think of in this case...

Comment: @forrestchev, you may add a list of fields for the second parameter of the cursor and do conditional checks on those for None.